# How to apply shadow color to Android EditText when focused?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText control in my application and when it is focused (i.e. I'm ready to enter something) I want to apply shadow color to it. How can I do this?

Thanks,
@nagaraju.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use the Selector tag  like Follows:**
Create a New xml file and place it in your drawable folder and name it as **shadow_color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ask_footer"/>
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/askfooter_hover" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ask_footer" />
</selector>
```

And then go to that xml in which your EditText is declared:
And write one attribute in editText

**android:background="@drawable/shadow_color"**
and you are done.

Comment: background is not the same as shadow color. This is not the proper solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a selector for your background drawable and create your own nine patches.

Comment: But i want to apply when i focused on it, if i write like stat_focused=true in item tag then it doesn't give me the shadowcolor property?

Comment: use a selector like this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Answer (score 0):

does shadow color mean you want a shadow theme background for your view??

then, assuming that you are using xml layout,the GU interface version shown on eclipse allows you to select a particular theme for your view,which i think is what you want.

if you want to put it manually,
you must mention it in the android manifest

eg.
`<activity android:name=".activity_name here"android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">//there are a handful of effects provided by SDK
</activity>`

i suggest the graphical user interface method,its easy and you can see the effect as you select the theme

Answer (score 0):

You can also check whether your EditText isFoucsed or not. And if true so change its background image to shadow like image.